# How can I process a sequence of images?

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing

I'm trying to create a sequence of image data.  However, when I run the code below, it doesn't show any errors, but when I look at the image data I created, only the last image from the sequence of images in the folder I'm referencing is stored.

When I verify the variable details of this image data, it only shows the last image.  There are 8 images all together and it only shows the last or 8th image.  What am I doing wrong?

```
clc; clear all; close all;
% Create an image filename, and read it in to a variable called manosData.

for k= 1:8
    jpgFileName = strcat('image', num2str(k),'.jpg');

    if exist(jpgFileName, 'file')
        manosData = imread(jpgFileName);
    else
        fprintf('File %s does not exist.\n', jpgFileName);
    end    
end

%%%and then save manosData
```

Answer (score 1):

That's because your loop is only saving the last image.  `manosData` only remembers the last image you read in because it keeps getting overwritten.  I don't know whether your images are colour or grayscale and I don't know if each image has the same resolution, so I would recommend you use cell arrays to handle this for reading in your images:

```
manosData = {}; %// Cell array
for k= 1:8    
    jpgFileName = strcat('image', num2str(k),'.jpg');

    if exist(jpgFileName, 'file') 
        manosData = [manosData imread(jpgFileName)]; %// Add image to cell array if possible    
    else
        fprintf('File %s does not exist.\n', jpgFileName);
    end    
end

%%%and then save manosData
```

You can then access any image by `manosData{k}`, where `k` is the image index.  As an example, if you want to show the fourth image, you'd do `imshow(manosData{4});`

Comment: Hi. the images are not the same resolution, and they are colour images. i tried you program and it works, but when i try to access manosData, to process all the images it gives me an error.                load manosData
for j=1:8
subplot(3,3,j)
dog1=reshape(image(:,j),64,64);
imshow(dog1)
end

Comment: image is the base name of all the images, for example image1.jpg, image2.jpg, etc.

Comment: That code doesn't make sense.  `image` is assumed to be a matrix yet this is a string.  I'm sorry I don't know what you want.

Comment: i want to modify everything that is in manosData, that program is an example that i got. any idea how can i plot all the images that manosData has and also reshape them. thanks for the help.